# vimeo.com shows Access Denied

Tags: video, security-warning, vimeo, zonealarm

Last few days I have noticed that, I can not access https://vimeo.com

Whenever I go to vimeo it responds with a blank page stating "Access Denied".

I have tried different methods to overcome this problem, but I did not find a solution.

Can anyone please tell me what should I do?

Currently I am using ZoneAlarm as firewall and antivirus.

Comment: Have you tried to ping vimeo?

Comment: Do you have ZoneAlarm's MITM feature enabled?  Can you provide us the certificate information that, the browser you are using, believes is correct?  Have you verified that the website is even up.  There are websites that will check that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your instant replay. Vimeo can be seen by proxy site. 
and can you please tell me what is ZoneAlarm's MITM feature? and how can i provide you certificate information?
Thank You

Comment: Are you using a proxy or a VPN ?

Comment: Thank you.
Now i am just using ZoneAlarm. and i have found that, when i remove zonealarm from my pc then vimeo works fine.
i think zonealarm block vimeos ip.
but i don't know how to solve that.
Thank You @HamzaAbbad

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Firewall or Antivirus blocks vimeo! You can try to whitelist it as Zonealarm describes [here](http://download.zonealarm.com/bin/inclient/ZA_HelpCenter/adding_sites.html):

> 1. Select Identity Protection|Trusted Sites, then click Add. The Add Trusted Site dialog appears.
> 2. Type the URL of the site (omit http://www), then click OK. After you click OK, ZoneAlarm security software verifies the site address
>      and records the IP address. This process can take several seconds.
> 3. Modify the site permissions as desired. By default, access and clear text password permissions for Custom sites are set to Ask.